# Convert month Name to month number and datetime to date using php and sql

Tags: php, sql

I need convert month Name to month number and datetime to date
date come from sql 1/oct/2013 0:00 need to convert 1/10/2013 how?
Very Thanks

Comment: It's kinda insane to store dates in a database like that, use date/time datatypes for those columns

Comment: datatype in db datetime and value 1/10/2013 12:00:00 AM

Comment: If the database holds a datetime, then why do you have this obscure format with a month name that you need to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing how to convert dates from one format to another is duplicated many times here on SO

```
$date = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('j/M/Y', '1/oct/2013');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

**EDIT**

If you absolutely can't update from a version of PHP that has been end of life since 6th January 2011, then you can convert your format to a slightly more regular format that will be recognised by strtotime()

```
$date = strtotime(str_replace('/','-','1/oct/2013'));
echo date('Y-m-d', $date), PHP_EOL;
```

But I'd strongly recommend updating your version of PHP.... or at least telling people what version you're running when you ask questions (because it makes a lot of difference to the answers you'll get)

Comment: not work this eror Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()

Comment: Then you're using a pretty old version of PHP: ConvertFromFormat() was introduced in version 5.3.0..... what version of PHP are you using? And you do realise that it's not a version that's supported any more.

Comment: I am used php5.2.9-2

Comment: Very Thanks Mark Baker it work prefect